# MongoDB - findOneAndUpdate() update using $set and $cond on single field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to update a field (statusObject.machineA.status) to 'working' in a database only if its value is 'waiting'. I have tried the following:

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate({
        $or: [
            {"statusObject.machineA.status":"waiting"},
            {"statusObject.machineB.status":"waiting"}
        ]
    }, [{
          $set: {
            "statusObject.machineA.status": {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$statusObject.machineA.status", "waiting"] },
                "working",
                "waiting"
              ]
            }
          }
       }], {
        new: true
    }, function(err, document) {});
```

My database looks like this:

```
var statusObject = {
        machineA:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        },
        machineB:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        }
};
```

For Example, I want the below JSON:

```
statusObject: {
        machineA:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        },
        machineB:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        }
}
```

to look like below after executing the query:

```
statusObject:{
        machineA:{
                status: 'working',
                buildProgress: 0
        },
        machineB:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        }
}

OR (Not Both)

statusObject:{
        machineA:{
                status: 'waiting',
                buildProgress: 0
        },
        machineB:{
                status: 'working',
                buildProgress: 0
        }
}
```

But after a little testing, I realized that the $cond object does not accept the field used in the $set i.e statusObject.machineA.status. That is, when I update one field based on another field's value, it works, but it doesn't work if I update a field based on its own value. No errors are shown, but the query just doesn't update the field.

Is there something wrong syntax-wise for the nested object or is it just not supported?
Any alternative method/s will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you give sample data in json, and the expected output in json? it can help to know what you need, and to test a query

Comment: Hey @Takis_ I have added the example above, I may be wrong using the $set and $cond together. Feel free to ignore my method.

Comment: your query looks fine, and it worked when i tested it, but you do this only for machineA, so machineB never changes, maybe you just need to write the same code for machineB also?

Comment: @Takis_ I am not getting even the first query to run. Can you share what version of mongo are you using, and also, does this work on mongoose too for you?

Comment: this is your code and runs for machineA ony [PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=622f2d926f902a4b4b2e75fc) (double click to run it). Maybe you need to add await? Its mongodb 5, but this query would run after mongodb 4.2 . Can you also check your driver/mongoose method to see if it accepts a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, aggregation pipelines are not supported for mongoose 5.xxx. I got it working by just updating my Mongoose to the latest one:

```
npm update mongoose
```

Thanks @[Takis _](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882692/takis)